# How to hide a custom user profile field on hook_disable in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a module that adds a field to the user profile. I used field_create_field and field_create_instance to do this. When I disable the module, I want the field to no longer show up on the user profile, but I do not want to destroy it. I want to be able to enable the module and have the field show up and the data to still be there as originally entered. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Here is the code I used to create the field:

```
  $field = array(
    'field_name'  => $field_name,
    'type'        => 'text',
    'visibility'  => 1,
    'category'    => 'API',
  );
  $field = field_create_field($field);
  $field_instance = array(
    'field_name'    => $field_name,
    'entity_type'   => 'user',
    'bundle'        => 'user',
    'label'         => t('API Token'),
    'cardinality'   => 1,
    'translatable'  => 0,
    'description'   => t('By using this API token, you agree to the site <a href="/about/site-policies/terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a> and to acknowledge that your submission does not include protected health information or personal identifiers.'),
    'widget'        => array(
      'type'        => 'text_textfield',
      'weight'      => 10,
    ),
    'formatter'     => array(
      'label'       => t('field formatter label'),
      'format'      => 'text_default'
    ),
    'settings'      => array(
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have created field using drupal entity like user, node etc then on that entity crud operation automatically apply.

As you have used api to "field_create_field" field then it automatically create field using api of entity vise verse its delete field when you uninstalled module.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I don't believe I understand your answer. Are you telling me that I can't hide it because of the way I created it? Would it hide automatically if I had created it differently? Remember, I just want to hide it when module is disabled, not delete it. I want it to reappear when the module is re-enabled. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First tell me when you uninstall your custom module then your custom field deleted from profile.? If yes then it's difficult to handle your use case. If no then in system table of Drupal you get status of your module whether it's disable or enable if status is 0 then used form alter hook of user profile and  hide field

Comment: When I disable the module the custom field does not get deleted, but when I uninstall the module, I am using field_delete_instance, so, yes, it is deleted from profile. Where would I put the hook_form_alter function? Would I need to create another module to hold that? I was hoping there was something I could call on hook_disable that would somehow set the field to hidden or disabled and not show it again until I reverse it on hook_enable. That way everything could be handled from my module. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Also, it is not too late to change the module. If there is a better way to create the field, I can easily do that.

Comment: I just watched the Drupalize Me video series on the Drupal 7 field API. I'm going to start over. I will post my solution here once it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to accomplish exactly what I wanted, but I ended up installing the field extra widgets module and hiding the field completely on the edit form. Then, I used hook menu alter to create a local task tabs and I display the field on that tab.